# Convert NSString to NSArray

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have one string as follows:

```js
NSString *str = @"abcd,efgh";
```

Now I want to convert this string into NSMutableArray like

```js
NSMutableArray *arr = {abcd,efgh};
```

then how can I do this?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very basic stuff, do your self a favor and read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)...

Comment: {abcd,efgh}; is a dictionary not array.In which form do you want to convert?

Answer (score 13):

```
NSArray *arr = [@"abcd,efgh" componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

should do the job.